# How to prove irreducibility of this polynomial?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

Let $p,q$ be primes.  Prove that $y^{n }-p$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[n ]q) $ .

I have tried for some time, but still feel confused about how to prove it. Can anyone help me?

Comment: This seems to hold only under the additional assumption that $p\ne\pm q$

Comment: Eisenstein${}$?

Comment: With that assumption, how can I prove it? Could you help me? @HagenvonEitzen

Comment: I don’t understand what you mean.@LordSharktheUnknown

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion

Comment: Maybe you are not far from solving it yourself. Write out what you tried. It should be easy since you've already done the work. It would be silly to waste it by not sharing it.

Comment: Here we work on the extension field $\mathbb{Q} (\sqrt[n]{q}) $ , not $\mathbb{Q}$ .@Dirk

Answer (score 1):

Set $F=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[n]{q},\varepsilon)$ where $\varepsilon$ be the $n^{\mathrm{th}}$ root of unity and $E$ be the splitting field of $x^n-p$ over $F$. As the roots of $x^n-p$ in $E$ are $\beta,\varepsilon\beta,\dots,\varepsilon^{n-1}\beta$, $x^n-p=\displaystyle\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}{(x-\varepsilon^k\beta)}$. Suppose $\psi$ is an irreducible factor of $x^n-p$ in $F[x]$, then $\psi=\displaystyle\prod_{\text{for some }k}{(x-\varepsilon^k\beta)}$, so the constant of $\psi$ is $\pm\varepsilon^c\beta^s$, so $\beta^s=r\in F$. However, $\deg\psi=s$, which means $\psi=x^s-r$. As $F(\beta)=F(\varepsilon\beta)=\cdots=F(\varepsilon^{n-1}\beta)$, the minimal polynomials of $\varepsilon^k\beta$ have the same degree $s$, so $x^n-q=\prod{(x^s-r_i)}$. So we have $s\mid n$ and $p=r_i^{n/s}$. To prove $s=n$, we only have to prove that $x^m=p$ has no root in $F$ for $m\ge2,m\mid n$, i.e., $\sqrt[m]{p}\not\in F$, which is obvious.

Answer (score -3):

Any root of a prime will be irrational. You can imagine trying to find roots of the polynomial in R and find there are no solutions in terms of radicals of other primes.